# Perl : Regex/File::Basename

Tags: perl

```
use File::Basename;
my $path = "a/b/c/d";
my $dirpath = basename ($path);
my $basepath = dirname ($path);
my $base_basepath = dirname ($basepath);
my $dir_dirpath = basename ($basepath);
print "$dir_dirpath/$dirpath\n";
```

I want c/d to be printed (i.e the list dir/filename). Is the above the best way to do that? The above obviously works but I somehow don't like it. Is there a better/cool/efficient way to do it? Something like a regex match??

Actually, that program just does a part of what I really want it to do. These are the different use cases and what the expected result is :

```
a/b/c/d => c/d d
b/c/d => c/d d
/c/d => c/d d
c/d => c/d d
/d => d
d => d
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`File::Spec`](https://metacpan.org/module/File%3a%3aSpec) module is the canonical and portable way to manipulate file paths, and 
[`File::Spec::Functions`](https://metacpan.org/module/File%3a%3aSpec%3a%3aFunctions) allows direct access to that module's functions without having to prefix them with `File::Spec->` everywhere.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Spec::Functions qw/ splitdir catdir /;

my $path = "a/b/c/d";
my @path = splitdir $path;
print catdir @path[-2,-1];
```

**output**

```
c/d
```

Answer (score 1):

#### One way using split

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $z="a/b/c/d";
my ($a, $b, $c, $d) = split ('/', $z);
print "$c/$d";
```

#### Using just a regex

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $z = "a/b/c/d"; 
($a, $b) = $z[$cnt] =~ m#(\w+){0,1}/{0,1}(\w+)$#;
printf "$a/$b - $b\n";
```

**NOTE:** This approach looks for trailing dir1/dir2 and saves them to `$a` and `$b`. The dollar sign ($) forces the match to anchor to the end of the string, so it's matching the right side or `$z`. The `{0,1}` allow for us to match something there if it's present, but if not then to ignore it. These are necessary for the `/d` and `d` cases.

#### All the possible paths demo

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my @z = qw(a/b/c/d b/c/d /c/d c/d);

for (my $cnt = 0; $cnt <= 3; $cnt++) {
  ($a, $b) = $z[$cnt] =~ m#(\w+){0,1}/{0,1}(\w+)$#;
  printf "%10s   -   %s/%s  -  %s\n", $z[$cnt], $a, $b, $b;
}

### output
% ./script.pl 
a/b/c/d   -   c/d  -  d
  b/c/d   -   c/d  -  d
   /c/d   -   c/d  -  d
    c/d   -   c/d  -  d
     /d   -   /d  -  d
      d   -   /d  -  d
```

This just shows that this approach works for the directories mentioned in the question.

**NOTE:** This approach does have it's cons. It will only work on UNIX systems and special attention needs to be paid to the **(\w+)** matcher for the directory names. If you have directories with spaces in them, this will fail.

Comment: Ah! I like the regex one. What if I want both c/d and d from a single regex? Is that possible? i.e., print c/d and d.

Comment: Thanks for being patient. If i have : a/b/c/d, or b/c/d or /c/d or c/d, i should get c/d and d. I will never have a /d or d case.

Comment: Modified the question above.

Comment: Super. Thank you. Lemme know if I can rate this very high... :-)